# Custom String Formatter

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel

I've written my custom implementation of an `f""` / `.format(...)`. I started the project thinking it was going to be longer than three lines.

```
from typing import List, Union, AnyStr

def format_string(string: str, variables: List[Union[str, int, float, bool, complex]]) -> str:
    """
    Formats the passed string with the passed list of variables

    >>> format_string("Hello, [*]", ["Ben"])
    Hello, Ben

    :param string -> str: String to be formatted
    :param variables -> List[Union[str, int, float, bool, complex]]: List of variables to format into string

    :return str: Formatted string
    """
    for index, value in enumerate(variables):
        string = string.replace("[*]", str(value), 1)
    return string
```

My main question is if it's possible to make this a one-liner. It absolutely infuriates me that I have to use three. I spent a long time trying a mixture of `*` and `''.join` to no avail. The code works, I would just like to shorten it up to one line. Of course, any and all feedback is appreciated and considered.

A secondary question is the method header. To represent `variables`, I have a `List` that can contain *any* types of variables. How would I go about representing this instead of having to list each type separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second point, since it's easier, `typing` has an [`Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any):

```
from typing import List, Any
. . ., variables: List[Any], . . .
```

For the first, you're just doing a [reduction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) over `variables`:

```
from typing import List, Any
from functools import reduce


def format_string(string: str, variables: List[Any]) -> str:
    return reduce(lambda s, val: s.replace("[*]", str(val), 1), variables, string)
```

Although really, in a real use case, I'd still split this over three lines for clarity:

```
def format_string(string: str, variables: List[Any]) -> str:
    return reduce(lambda s, val: s.replace("[*]", str(val), 1),
                  variables, 
                  string)
```

And honestly, I might just make that function var-arg instead of grouping things in a list to make it consistent with other `format` functions:

```
def format_string(string: str, *variables: Any) -> str:
    return reduce(lambda s, val: s.replace("[*]", str(val), 1), variables, string)

>>> format_string("[*] Hello [*]", 1, 2)
'1 Hello 2'
```

Note that when annotating a a var-arg parameter, you annotate the type of each element and ignore the type of the wrapping container (a tuple iirc). That means it's `*variables: Any`, not `*variables: Tuple[... Any]`.

---

Of course though, whether or not this is better is a matter of taste, but this is the ideal use-case for `reduce`. Whenever you want to constantly reassign one thing in a simple loop, `reduce` is likely a good tool to look at.

Comment: What a beautiful solution, I knew there was a way to one line this. Thanks!